# Type of the return value must be pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.renderable.Renderable; got ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox instead

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, pandas-profiling

It can't show the report as widgets in Pandas Profiling.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling as pp
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ssj\\Desktop\\Thesis\\StockMartket.csv')

type(df)
df
```

`profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")`

`profile.to_widgets()`

`

```
Summarize dataset:   0%|          | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Generate report structure:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Render widgets:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 profile.to_widgets()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py:466, in ProfileReport.to_widgets(self)
    462     pass
    464 from IPython.core.display import display
--> 466 display(self.widgets)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py:251, in ProfileReport.widgets(self)
    246     raise RuntimeError(
    247         "Widgets interface not (yet) supported for comparing reports, please use the HTML rendering."
    248     )
    250 if self._widgets is None:
--> 251     self._widgets = self._render_widgets()
    252 return self._widgets

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1037, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)
   1036 except TypeError as exc:
-> 1037     raise TypeError(*exc.args) from None
   1039 # If a generator is returned, wrap it if its yield/send/return types can be checked
   1040 if inspect.isgenerator(retval) or isasyncgen(retval):

TypeError: type of the return value must be pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.renderable.Renderable; got ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox instead
```

`

Instead, I don't have problems with the command prompt:

`profile.to_notebook_iframe()`

I also had problems at first, but I did an update pandas profiling and this one works.

I point out that at the very beginning, a few weeks everything worked. After a few weeks, unfortunately, I have problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GipB.png)

I have a problem to see the report in the form of widgets. A type error pops up:

`Type of the return value must be pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.renderable.Renderable; got ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox instead`

I will be grateful for help.